# Lat-lon contour plots using geographic projections

Tags: visualization, geodesy

I need to create contour plots of (lat,lon) quantities projected on geographic regions using different projections. Usually considering the entire world or hemispheres. Coastlines need to be present below the contour plot.
I have not been able to find any examples, anybody considered a similar problem ?
Thanks

Comment: Hello, and welcome to Mathematica.  The more specific detail you include in your question the more likely you are to receive a good answer, in my experience.  Also to what degree are you already familiar with the included [**Maps & Cartography**](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/guide/MapsAndCartography.html) functionality?

Comment: Please consider taking the [tour](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/tour). Also [editing your question](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/editing-help) to share what you know, what you have tried and [make it a good question](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask). Particularly, include a minimum example of the code you are working on and examples of the desired output.