# How to ContourPlot a function of the coordinates on the Earth's surface on a map projection

Tags: plotting, curated-data, geography

There are two similar questions ([this](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/60270/lat-lon-contour-plots-using-geographic-projections) and [this](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/60270/lat-lon-contour-plots-using-geographic-projections)), but one is too specific and the other is apparently not clear and has no answers. I'll try to make the question more complete.

Suppose you have a vector field depending on the coordinates x,y,z of a point on the Earth's surface *[Edit: I found a mistake on this expression but to keep discussions consistent I'll leave as is.]*

```
field = With[{rl$ = 
    Transpose[{{1.45031*10^7, -1.46446*10^11}, {-3.86086*10^8, 
        2.25113*10^8}, {1.00319*10^8, 3.47297*10^10}} - 1. {##1}]}, 
  Total[({4.90254*10^12, 1.32705*10^20} rl$)/rl$^3] - 
   1. {-0.00569904, -0.0000209977, 0.00135953}] &
```

With some trick I can represent the Norm of this vector field on a map **with the equirectangular projection**. If I well understood the topic:

*[Edit: I found another supposed mistake in the original code following. From what I now understand on a map usaully we represent the **geodetic** latitude. But the well known parametrization of an oblate spheroid (the one I originally used) refers to the **geocentric** latitude. The difference between the two expression is not more than about 0.2° for GRS80, but to be rigorous we need to take into account this difference. This is the reason for the function `toGeocentric` I added.  Feel free to comment on this to confirm or to contradict my understanding of this topic.]*

```
{a, b} = GeodesyData["GRS80", #] & /@ {"SemimajorAxis", 
     "SemiminorAxis"} // UnitConvert // QuantityMagnitude

toGeocentric = λ \[Function] 
  Evaluate[GeodesyData[
     "GRS80", {"GeocentricLatitude", λ}] /. λ -> λ °]

gg = GeoGraphics[GeoRange -> "World", 
  GeoProjection -> "Equirectangular", 
  GeoGridLines -> Quantity[15, "AngularDegrees"], ImageSize -> 800]

cp = ContourPlot[
  Norm[field[a Cos[toGeocentric @θ °] Cos[φ °], 
    a Cos[toGeocentric @θ °] Sin[φ °], 
    b Sin[toGeocentric @θ °]]], {φ, -180, 
   180}, {θ, -90, 90}, 
  ColorFunction -> (Opacity[0.6, ColorData["TemperatureMap"][#]] &)]

Show[Graphics @@ gg, cp]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

It is the "right" way to do that (I'm a bit concerned by `Graphics@@gg` for example, I read that on another question)?

It is possible to use many projections (ideally *all* map projections supported by *Mathematica*) in a consistent and general way *without having to know and to input all the necessary projection transformations but taking advantage of the cartography framework in Mathematica*?

I'm interested for example to `"LambertAzimuthal", "Bonne", "Robinson"`...

Comment: "different projections" - so as long as you know the explicit expressions for $\theta$ and $\varphi$ in terms of the other projection's coordinates, you just plug things in, yes?

Comment: Yes, I suppose. But, If possible, I prefer a way that can handle ideally all (more common, world's) map projections supported by Mathematica without even having to know and to input all the details of these projection transformations.

Answer (score 23):

You can use your `ContourPlot`, you just need to wrap coordinates with `GeoPosition`, note that you have to flip order. (*if x is longitude and y is latitude, because `GeoPosition` assumes first is latitude and so on.*)

`cp` is `Graphics[GraphicsComplex[coordinates, primitives]...]`, it is convenient to use this form. We can apply `GeoPosition` in one place and reduce amout of calls to Wolfram server:

```
MapAt[GeoPosition[#[[;; , {2, 1}]]] &, cp[[1]], {1}]
```

`#[[;;,{2,1}]]` means from `{{x1, y1}, {x2, y2}...}` we get `{{y1, x1}, {y2, x2}...`

So:

```
GeoGraphics[MapAt[GeoPosition[#[[;; , {2, 1}]]] &, cp[[1]], {1}], 
  GeoRange -> "World", GeoProjection -> "Robinson", 
  GeoGridLines -> Quantity[15, "AngularDegrees"], ImageSize -> 800]
```

And with those `GeoPositions` `GeoGraphics` will convert everything automatically.

[image]

I think this answer of mine is **related** because I'm using projections without knowing their forms: [Mollweide maps in Mathematica](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/72549/5478)

In general `GeoGraphics` are a little crippled because they are not handling plot range, cutting primitives on edge and similar cases.

<strike>There is also a **bug** which makes that even harder: [Compability between Graphics coordinates and shifted projections in GeoGraphics](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/72476/5478)</strike>

So very often you will have to handle coordinates carefully as **it won't work automatically for every projection**:

It works for most projections, old bug was fixed but there are new issues I need to investigate for problematic cases:

```
{a, b} = GeodesyData["GRS80", #] & /@ {"SemimajorAxis", "SemiminorAxis"} // UnitConvert // QuantityMagnitude

cp = ContourPlot[ Norm[field[a Cos[θ Degree] Cos[φ Degree],   a Cos[θ Degree] Sin[φ Degree],  b Sin[θ Degree]]],
  {φ, -180,  180}, {θ, -90, 90},
  ColorFunction -> (Opacity[0.6, Blend["TemperatureMap", #]] &), 
  ContourStyle -> Directive[Thick, Dashed], Contours -> 4];

data = MapAt[
  GeoPosition[#[[A ll, {2, 1}]]] &, 
  Cases[cp, _GraphicsComplex, Infinity][[1]],
  {1}
]
GeoGraphics[data, GeoRange -> "World", GeoProjection -> #, 
  GeoGridLines -> Quantity[15, "AngularDegrees"], 
  ImageSize -> {300, 300}, PlotLabel -> #, LabelStyle -> 18
] & /@ GeoProjectionData[][[;; 3]]
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks. This is the approach I was searching. Two possible issue: the first is that many projections are supported but some aren't. The second is: we use ContourPlot to adaptively sample the function on an Equirectangular projection but later we use these samples on another projection plane: this can eventually produce non-smooth contours with more complex functions? I understand you already did much for me, so if you can just give me a hint...

Comment: He's saying that the adaptive algorithm of `ContourPlot[]` gave a result adapted to equirectangular coordinates; if you then transform those sample points to, say, sinusoidal coordinates, the result might look rougher than it would have been if the algorithm adapted to the new coordinates.

Comment: @J. M. I see, well, I don't know any good solution if we don't have those transformations.

Comment: One could try, to set MaxRecursion->1 and add many PlotPoints to not waste time on features that may not be relevant in target coordinates

Comment: @J. M. Thanks for translating

Answer (score 7):

[image: Animation]

Trying to handle the two concerns expressed in a comment to the Kuba answer, I built my own method.

Indeed, I have investigated and tested 6 methods but the one I consider a good compromise between supported projections, (supposed) accuracy and speed is the following.

```
Options[GeoContourPlot] = Join[
   Options[GeoGraphics],
   FilterRules[Options[ContourPlot], 
    Complement @@ (Map[First]@*Options /@ {ContourPlot, GeoGraphics})]
   ];

GeoContourPlot[fun_, opts : OptionsPattern[]] :=
Module[{gg, gp, geoModel, geoProjection, bmesh, mesh, vlp, vlc, fl, 
  cp},
 gg = GeoGraphics[FilterRules[{opts}, Options[GeoGraphics]]];
 {geoModel, geoProjection} = {GeoModel, GeoProjection} /. 
   AbsoluteOptions[gg, {GeoModel, GeoProjection}];
 gp = FirstCase[gg, 
   Polygon[vl_, ___, VertexTextureCoordinates -> _, ___] :> 
    Polygon[Developer`ToPackedArray@vl], $Failed, \[Infinity]];
 (* Area[gp] sometimes never ends: Area[bmesh] is immediate *)
 bmesh = BoundaryDiscretizeRegion@gp;
 mesh = TriangulateMesh[bmesh,
   MaxCellMeasure -> Area@bmesh/Times @@ (OptionValue[PlotPoints] /.
          {Automatic -> 250} /. {n : 
            Except[_List] :> {n}} /. {{n_} :> {n, n}})
   ];
 vlp = GeoGridPosition[MeshCoordinates[mesh], geoProjection, geoModel];
 vlc = Quiet[
   GeoPositionXYZ[vlp], {CompiledFunction::cfne, Power::infy, 
    Infinity::indet, GeoPosition::ltrng}];
 If[! MatrixQ[vlc[[1]], NumericQ],
  (* For few projections, the way I used to get the projected domain is unreliable, 
  not all projected nodes can be unprojected, so it's necessary to process one at time (slow!) *)
  vlc = Quiet[
    GeoPositionXYZ /@ Thread@vlp, {CompiledFunction::cfne, 
     Power::infy, Infinity::indet, GeoPosition::ltrng}];
  With[{sel = FreeQ[#, GeoGridPosition] & /@ vlc},
   vlp = MapAt[Pick[#, sel] &, vlp, {1}];
   vlc = GeoPositionXYZ[
     Pick[vlc, sel][[All, 1]] // Developer`ToPackedArray]
   ];
  ];
 fl = fun @@@ vlc[[1]];
 cp = ListContourPlot[MapThread[Append, {vlp[[1]], fl}], 
   Evaluate@FilterRules[{opts}, Options[ListContourPlot]]];
 GeoGraphics[cp[[1]], FilterRules[{opts}, Options[GeoGraphics]]]
 ]
```

The results are promising:

```
gl = Table[
   GeoContourPlot[Norm@*field,
    GeoRange -> All, GeoProjection -> geoProjection, 
    GeoGridLines -> Quantity[15, "AngularDegrees"], 
    GeoRangePadding -> Scaled@.1,
    ImageSize -> {200, 200}, PlotPoints -> 50, PlotRangePadding -> .2,
     PlotLabel -> geoProjection,
    ColorFunction -> (Opacity[0.6, ColorData["TemperatureMap"][#]] &),
     ContourStyle -> Thin, Contours -> 8        ],
   {geoProjection, 
    DeleteCases[GeoProjectionData[], 
     s_String /; 
      StringMatchQ[s, 
       StartOfString ~~ ("SPCS" | "UTMZone" | "UPS") ~~ __]]}
   ];
Grid[Partition[gl, 5, 5, {1, -1}, ""], Dividers -> All]
```

[image]

Some projection is still unsupported and I made choices that deserve furter investigations, but for me, I think these results are enough.

If someone is interested, in a future update to this self-answer, I can add some details on the other methods and on some choice made for this method.

Comment: Nice results :)

Comment: @Kuba Thanks, but still unsatisfied by the unreliable way used to get the domain on the projected plane...

Comment: Polygons should be automatically cut on edge or antimeridian, this functionality is just Beta version! ps. take a look at Mercator and MillerCylindrical, don't you think that something is odd in area of inner disks? It looks like sometimes area of SouthAmerica taken is varying.

Comment: This is astonishing example of d3.geo library: http://www.jasondavies.com/maps/transition/ I tired to do the same, it is notpossible in MMA  unless you fix GeoGraphics for Wolfram. So I decided I have no time for that :/