# Can A Plot Be Overlayed With A Map?

Tags: plotting, data, map, geography

Some brief, only slightly important background.
I am doing a research project using the data from NASA's GRACE mission. I wrote a short Perl script to take two data files and find the change in groundwater between the two dates. This gave me a set of 64,800 3D coordinates (One for every degree latitude and longitude on the Earth's surface). Using Mathematica, I created a ListDensityPlot to visualize the changes in groundwater. As you can see from the code below, the way I deal with clipping is pretty clumsy and doesn't look very good on the map. Otherwise, I am pretty happy with this plot. It pretty well shows everything I want it to. Most of the code courtesy of @Mr.Wizard.

```
den = ListDensityPlot[jpl200313,ColorFunction ->(ColorData["ThermometerColors"][1 - #] &),
    ClippingStyle -> {RGBColor[0.5, 0.02, 0.03],RGBColor[0, 0.01, 0.56]},
    PlotLegends ->BarLegend[Automatic,LegendMarkerSize -> 180,LegendFunction -> "Frame",
    LegendMargins -> 5,LegendLabel -> "Water Level Change (cm)"],PlotRange -> {-20, 20}];
prim = First@Cases[den, Graphics[a_, ___] :> a, {0, -1}, 1];
geo = GeoGraphics[{Opacity[0.6], prim},GeoBackground -> GeoStyling["StreetMapNoLabels"], 
   ImageSize -> 1000];
geo~Legended~den[[2]]
```

[image: This shows global change in groundwater (in centimeters),from July 2003 to July 2013]

The final piece that I would like to figure out is how to narrow down to specific countries while keeping the legend. Eventually I will build a table or possibly an animate function of several maps of the same country with time being the manipulatable variable. These pictures are from code courtesy of @FJRA.

```
southamerica =ListDensityPlot[jpl200313, AspectRatio -> 1/2, Frame->None, 
   PlotRangePadding -> 0, PlotRange -> {-20, 20},ColorFunction ->
    (ColorData["ThermometerColors"][1 - #] &)];
img1 = Rasterize[southamerica, "Image", RasterSize -> 360];
img2 = SetAlphaChannel[img1, .8];
geoplot = GeoGraphics[{GeoStyling[{"GeoImage", img2},GeoRange -> {{-90, 90}, {-180, 180}}],
    Polygon[EntityClass["Country", "SouthAmerica"]]},GeoBackground ->
    GeoStyling["StreetMapNoLabels"],GeoZoomLevel -> 3,GeoProjection -> "Equirectangular"]
```

The code for the picture of India is identical except for the name and the Entity function. 
[image: South America changes in groundwater]
[image: India changes in groundwater]

Anyway, my big question at this point is whether or not the functionality of looking at individual countries can be combined with the readability of the first plot where I can add legends, titles labels etc. Thanks again!

Comment: What projection are you using for the plot above?

Comment: That projection is completely square. That is the latitude and longitude lines make a perfect grid.

Comment: I think based on that a simple method will work.  Please attempt to apply my method and see if it aligns correctly.

Comment: You're welcome.  You may want to hold off on the Accept however as there are probably prettier ways to do it than simply setting `Opacity[0.5]`.

Comment: related: [How to ContourPlot a function of the coordinates on the Earth's surface on a map projection](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/83050/5478)

Comment: disc otter, I am sorry for any inconvenience I have caused you but it seems the Google Drive file is private.  (It wants me to sign in.)  I do not use Google Drive myself so I don't know how this works, but I know I have downloaded files from Google Drive that other people have shared so it must be possible to make something public.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

*Please see the **Utility function** section for a concise summary.*

An arbitrary density plot for the example:

```
den = DensityPlot[Sin[x] Sin[y], {x, -180, 180}, {y, -90, 90}]
```

[image]:

Extract the graphics primitives from the density plot:

```
prim = First @ Cases[den, Graphics[a_, ___] :> a, {0, -1}, 1];
```

Plot them directly with [`GeoGraphics`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/GeoGraphics.html) while setting the desired [`GeoStyling`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/GeoStyling.html) for the [`GeoBackground`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/GeoBackground.html):

```
GeoGraphics[
  {Opacity[0.8], prim},
  GeoBackground -> GeoStyling["ReliefMap"]
]
```

[image]

With `GeoStyling["ContourMap"]`:

[image]

`ImageSize` proves to be important; with `"StreetMapNoLabels"` an and and `ImageSize` of 512 or less no country borders are shown; 513 or greater and they are:

```
GeoGraphics[
  {Opacity[0.6], prim},
  GeoBackground -> GeoStyling["StreetMapNoLabels"], 
  ImageSize -> 600
]
```

[image]

---

#### Projections

To enable arbitrary projections we need to convert the plain coordinates in in the `DensityPlot` primitives to [`GeoPosition`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/GeoPosition.html) coordinates.  `prim` as extracted above is a [`GraphicsComplex`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/GraphicsComplex.html) object which we can convert with:

```
prim2 = MapAt[GeoPosition @* Map[Reverse], prim, 1];
```

Now:

```
GeoGraphics[
  {Opacity[0.7], prim2},
  GeoBackground -> GeoStyling["StreetMapNoLabels"], 
  ImageSize -> 700,
  GeoProjection -> "Albers"
]
```

[image]

#### Legends

Including the legend from the original `DensityPlot` may be done like this:

```
den = DensityPlot[Sin[x] Sin[y], {x, -180, 180}, {y, -90, 90},
        PlotLegends -> Automatic];

prim = First @ Cases[den, Graphics[a_, ___] :> a, {0, -1}, 1];

geo = GeoGraphics[{Opacity[0.6], prim},
        GeoBackground -> GeoStyling["StreetMapNoLabels"], 
        ImageSize -> 600];

geo ~Legended~ den[[2]]
```

[image]

---

### Utility function

The methods above may be combined into a single utility function.

```
toGeoGraphics[
  Shortest[opac : _?NumericQ : 0.6],
  opts : OptionsPattern[GeoGraphics]
][in_] :=
  With[{trans = If[MatchQ[OptionValue[GeoProjection], Automatic | "Equirectangular"], {},
     gc_GraphicsComplex :> MapAt[GeoPosition@*Map[Reverse], gc, 1]]},
    in /. Graphics[prim_, ___] :>
      GeoGraphics[{Opacity @ opac, prim /. trans}, opts, Options @ toGeoGraphics]
  ]
```

Define any default options that you want:

```
Options[toGeoGraphics] =
  {GeoBackground -> GeoStyling["StreetMapNoLabels"], 
   ImageSize -> 600};
```

Now use it like this:

```
DensityPlot[Sin[x] Sin[y], {x, -180, 180}, {y, -90, 90},
 PlotLegends -> Automatic] // 
   toGeoGraphics[GeoProjection -> "Mollweide"]
```

[image]

The first parameter of `toGeoGraphics` is the opacity; the remainder are any options you wish to pass to `GeoGraphics`, overriding defaults.

```
big = DensityPlot[Sin[x/38] Sin[y/25], {x, -180, 180}, {y, -90, 90}, 
  ColorFunction -> "CMYKColors", PlotPoints -> 100, MeshFunctions -> {#3 &, #3 &}, 
  Mesh -> {Range[-1, 1, 0.4], Range[-0.8, 0.8, 0.4]}, MeshStyle -> {Black, Dashed}, 
  PlotLegends -> Automatic];

big // toGeoGraphics[0.4, GeoProjection -> "Albers"]
```

[image]

Comment: @discotter Did you respect the `First @ den` part of my proposal?  You need to extract the primitives from the `Graphics` expression or you will get that message.  If you *still* get it I will take another look at this.

Comment: No, I'm sorry. It did end up working. Apparently the PlotLegend piece of my code brought up the graphics error. Once I removed the PlotLegend command, I was able to combine them. Are there any projections I can use that don't have the continent and ocean names on them?

Comment: @discotter I didn't consider legends; indeed a plot with a legend will have a format of `Legended[Graphics[ . . . ], . . . ]` and you would need to strip that too, e.g. `First @ First @ den` or `den[[1, 1]]`.  Perhaps more robust would be `FirstCase[den, Graphics[a_, ___] :> a, {}, {0, -1}]`.  Good question about the labels; let me check and get back to you.

Comment: @discotter I realized that I was over-complicating things with `Epilog`.  Please see the update.

Comment: Wow! That looks great. I did a sample run with "ReliefMap" styling. I included the picture above in my original question. Unfortunately the clipping issue still makes it look weird but I'll continue to tinker with that. This has been quite helpful. Thank You.

Comment: The StreetMapNoLabels option is _exactly_ what I wanted. However, the country borders won't show up on my plot. Is there a reason for this?

Comment: @discotter (1) I don't know why country borders are missing; which version of *Mathematica* are you using? (2) Can you upload the data somewhere so that I may examine the clipping issue for myself?

Comment: I am using Mathematica 10. Where should I upload the data so that it is easily accessible?

Comment: Are you sure the command you used was "StreetMapNoLabels"? Even when I directly copied your code and attempted to overlay it on your arbitrary density plot, country borders didn't show up at all.

Comment: @discotter It seems `ImageSize` is important, which I did not realize.  Without it I get no country borders either.  My exact code for the last plot is: `GeoGraphics[{Opacity[0.6], prim}, GeoBackground -> GeoStyling["StreetMapNoLabels"], 
 ImageSize -> 600]`.  For upload try perhaps http://pastebin.com/ or Google Drive?  Or maybe your ISP gives you a small personal web storage area?

Comment: If you give me your email, I can send you the CSV notepad file as an attachment.

Comment: @discotter I am sorry but I prefer not to disseminate my email address more than I already have.  Perhaps you could `Select` a small region of the data where clipping occurs (like Alaska) and post that.

Comment: If you want to see the _country borders_, it has to be at least zoom 2. You can force a particular zoom by using the `GeoZoomLevel` option, or using an explicit `ImageSize` that would make the `Automatic` zoom to be greater than 1.

Comment: A word of caution: The legend does not account for the opacity of the density/contour plot, which might cause difficulties connecting the colors to their corresponding values. (+1 of course)

Comment: @FJRA Thank you.

Comment: @shrx A valid warning.  I'll see what I can do about that later if I have time/memory/interest enough.

Comment: This is more help than I would have ever imagined I would receive. Thank you so much @Mr. Wizard. The amount of effort and time you put into this answer is incredible.

Comment: @discotter I am curious: why did you Accept the other answer instead?  Regardless you are welcome.  I'll still see if I can improve the legend consistency if I have time.

Comment: I'm curious too, I would have chosen yours @Mr.Wizard !

Comment: @MR. Wizard Sorry for the confusion. I don't know much about Stack Exchange yet. I had accepted Mr.Wizard's answer first, but then took pieces from both of them because they were both very helpful. I accepted the second answer thinking I could accept both not realizing that it made me unaccept the other. Honestly they were both very helpful.

Comment: @discotter No problem and thanks for the Accept.  Know that the Accept is always yours to do with as you please; I was merely curious after the glowing review why you would Accept another and now I know.  FJRA, thank you.

Comment: One final comment. With your method, @Mr.Wizard, is there a way to look at individual sections of the world? It would be nice to be able to zoom in and highlight specific countries or continents. Thanks!

Comment: @discotter Good question.  I'll look into that.  I just noticed and corrected a syntax error in my `toGeoGraphics` code in case it was causing you problems.

Comment: @discotter Plotting over a smaller region appears to work by default except for an unwanted border:  `DensityPlot[Sin[x/180] Sin[y/180], {x, 40, 180}, {y, 30, 90}] // toGeoGraphics[]`.  If you have a full-size `DensityPlot` and you want to zoom that can be done with `PlotRange` (without the unwanted border) like this: `DensityPlot[Sin[x] Sin[y], {x, -180, 180}, {y, -90, 90}] // 
 toGeoGraphics[PlotRange -> {{40, 180}, {30, 90}}]` however that does not combine with `GeoProjection`.  What is your desired workflow?

Comment: @Mr.Wizard I will post a fairly sizable edit to my original question in an effort to show some things.

Answer (score 10):

I would prefer to use the `"GeoImage"` styling, because you can use other projections when using it.

Let's say you have data for the whole world in a matrix:

```
data = Table[
  Sin[x Degree] Sin[y Degree], {y, -90, 90}, {x, -180, 180}]
```

Then you use `ListDensityPlot`:

```
den1 = ListDensityPlot[data, AspectRatio -> 1/2, Frame -> None, 
  PlotRangePadding -> 0];
```

And convert it to an image, and add some transparency level:

```
img1 = Rasterize[den1, "Image", RasterSize -> 360];
img2 = SetAlphaChannel[img1, .5]
```

[image]

Then you can use `GeoStyling` with `"GeoImage"`:

```
GeoGraphics[{GeoStyling[{"GeoImage", img2}, 
   GeoRange -> {{-90, 90}, {-180, 180}}], 
  FilledCurve[
   GeoPath[{{-90, -180}, {90, -180}, {90, 0}, {90, 180}, {-90, 
      180}, {-90, 0}}, "Rhumb"]]}, GeoRange -> "World", 
 GeoBackground -> GeoStyling["StreetMapNoLabels"], GeoZoomLevel -> 2]
```

[image]

As I said, the good thing is that you can *project* it (but be careful with the `GeoPath`, needs to be modified for some projections that are not defined in the poles):

```
GeoGraphics[{GeoStyling[{"GeoImage", img2}, 
   GeoRange -> {{-90, 90}, {-180, 180}}], 
  FilledCurve[
   GeoPath[{{-86, -180}, {86, -180}, {86, 0}, {86, 180}, {-86, 
      180}, {-86, 0}}, "Rhumb"]]}, GeoRange -> "World", 
 GeoBackground -> GeoStyling["StreetMapNoLabels"], GeoZoomLevel -> 2, 
 GeoProjection -> "Mercator"]
```

[image]

Or clip only an specific area:

```
GeoGraphics[{GeoStyling[{"GeoImage", img2}, 
   GeoRange -> {{-90, 90}, {-180, 180}}], 
  Polygon[EntityClass["Country", "SouthAmerica"]]}, 
 GeoBackground -> GeoStyling["StreetMapNoLabels"], GeoZoomLevel -> 3, 
 GeoProjection -> "LambertAzimuthal"]
```

[image]

Comment: I added projections to my method as well. +1 for making me step up my game. :-)

Comment: @FJRA This is great! However, I am still encountering one problem. Is there any way to keep a Plot Legend on the side of the map? For this data, it is pretty important that the viewer be able to see the units of what the density plot is showing. Is there a way to keep the plot legend separate and not combine it as part of the image? Thanks!

Comment: @discotter I updated my answer for legends.