# How to align GeoGraphics "GeoImage" with GeoPositions?

Tags: plotting, geography, geodesy, overlay

I have latitude and longitude locations that I need density (or contour) plot to overlay on a map. For example:

```
dat = {{40.5`, -111.35`}, {37.84`, -112.87`}, {38.79`, -112.05`}, 
{40.28`, -109.23`}, {38.79`, -112.04`}, {41.42`, -112.87`}, {37.09`, 
-112.9`}, {37.82`, -113.1`}, {42, -112.6`}, {39.58`, -111.69`}, 
{40.69`, -109.31`}, {38.074`, -112.192`}, {38.71`, -112.43`}, 
{38.73`, -112.44`}, {38.73`, -112.45`}, {38.72`, -112.46`}, {38.71`, 
-112.44`}, {38.73`, -112.44`}, {41.42`, -112.87`}, {38.88`, 
-111.98`}, {38.86`, -111.97`}, {38.89`, -111.98`}, {39.75`, 
-110.84`}, {40.61`, -109.41`}};
ad = AdministrativeDivisionData[{"Utah", "UnitedStates"}];

GeoGraphics[{Gray, ad["Polygon"], Red, PointSize[.01], 
  Point[GeoPosition /@ Rest@dat]}, GeoBackground -> None]
```

[image]

I create the density plot.

```
sdh = SmoothDensityHistogram[Reverse[dat, 2], PlotRange -> Full, 
  PlotRangePadding -> None, Frame -> False, ImagePadding -> None]
```

[image]

However, when I overlay it on the geographic region the density plot is not aligned with the geographic locations.

```
GeoGraphics[{
  {Gray, GeoStyling[{"GeoImage", sdh}], ad["Polygon"]},
  {Red, PointSize[.01], Point[GeoPosition /@ Rest@dat]}},
 GeoBackground -> None]
```

[image]

What am I doing wrong? Should I be using something other than `"GeoImage"`?

Comment: Are you looking for something like [this](http://i.stack.imgur.com/cLm4Q.png)?  To get it, I extracted the polygon and used it as the `RegionFunction` for the histogram plot

Comment: @JasonB Yes. That is what I am looking for. Although it is not a `GeoGraphics` it may be a good workaround if nothing else materializes. Please post as an answer.

Comment: @Edmund Probably you can use the method shown in this WC post: "[Mass shootings and availability of gun dealerships](http://community.wolfram.com/groups/-/m/t/873886?p_p_auth=Ut601a4V)."

Comment: I think your code is basically correct. Just change PlotRange->Full to PlotRange -> Reverse[GeoBounds[ad]] in the definition of sdh.

Comment: @jose - Nice catch, I just stole that and put it in my answer below

Comment: @jose Yes, that does the trick.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

jose gave the best answer this question in comments, so I will add it here.  As plotted, the `PlotRange` of the density plot is `{{-113.032, -109.298}, {36.3135, 42.7765}}`, but the `GeoBounds` for the map is `{{-114.051, -109.045}, {36.9991, 42.0016}}`.  Apparently this mismatch is the problem.

```
sdh = SmoothDensityHistogram[Reverse[dat, 2], 
   PlotRangePadding -> None, Frame -> False, ImagePadding -> None, 
   PlotRange -> Reverse[GeoBounds[ad]]];
GeoGraphics[{{Gray, GeoStyling[{"GeoImage", sdh}], 
   ad["Polygon"]}, {Red, PointSize[.01], Point[GeoPosition /@ dat]}}, 
 GeoBackground -> None]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

I give a couple of alternate methods below as well.

### Workaround 1 - `Graphics` using the geo-polygon

I remembered doing something similar [here](http://community.wolfram.com/groups/-/m/t/853293),

```
utah = DiscretizeGraphics[
   AdministrativeDivisionData[{"Utah", "UnitedStates"}, "Polygon"]];
SmoothDensityHistogram[
 Reverse[dat, 2],
 PlotRange -> Full,
 PlotRangePadding -> None,
 Frame -> False,
 ImagePadding -> None,
 RegionFunction -> Function[{x, y},
   {x, y} ∈ utah],
 AspectRatio -> Automatic,
 Epilog -> {Red, PointSize[.01], Point@*Reverse /@ dat}]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

### Workaround 2 - Extract the `Graphics` primitives and feed them to `GeoGraphics`

This is actually my favorite method.  Here we take the trick from the of forming the plot using a `RegionFunction`, and combine it with Mr. Wizard's [method](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/84601/9490) for inserting `Graphics` into `GeoGraphics`:

```
reg1 = DiscretizeGraphics[
   AdministrativeDivisionData[{"Utah", "UnitedStates"}, "Polygon"]];
sdh = SmoothDensityHistogram[Reverse[dat, 2], PlotRange -> Full, 
   PlotRangePadding -> None, Frame -> False, ImagePadding -> None, 
   RegionFunction -> Function[{x, y}, {x, y} \[Element] reg1]];
prim = First@Cases[sdh, Graphics[a_, ___] :> a, {0, -1}, 1];
GeoGraphics[{prim, Red, PointSize[.01], 
  Point[GeoPosition /@ Rest@dat]}, GeoBackground -> None]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Comment: The regions lose their proportions when this method is used.  They don't look like their `GeoGraphics` counterparts. This one is ok because it is essentially a box but others do not far as well. Also does not handle complicated borders very well. Thanks for the effort, though. (+1)

Comment: Nice wrap-up of the workaround and the answer.