# Creating a map of earth from an unknown region of the sphere

Tags: plotting, graphics, regions, textures

Lately I've been trying to use Mathematica to plot a map of earth.
I have an analytic function from a known triangle to some part of a unit sphere, described by unknown parametrization. This function $f$ gets a point $(x,y)$ and returns a point on the sphere $(X,Y,Z)$. I can invert the function numerically to get $f^{-1}$ using `findroot`.
I want to plot a map of earth on the triangluar region – the map that you get by using $f^{-1}$ on the corresponding region of the sphere.

I've tried many things but none worked. At the begining I thought to use `GeoProjection` from [Maps & Cartography](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/60270/lat-lon-contour-plots-using-geographic-projections), but it doesn't seem to support projections that are not predefined. It also provieds very pixelated maps, and I hoped to get a higher resolution one.
I also tried to use `ParametricPlot` to map from the triangle to the sphere by using $f$, using `TextureCoordinateFunction` to plot a texture of earth on the sphere, and map back to the triangle by $f^{-1}$, but didn't mange to get it work.

How can you make such a map in Mathematica?

Thanks!

Comment: Is there some reason you can’t convert the points on the unit sphere to longitude and latitude?

Comment: @Pillsy Can you please elaborate? I can't do it analytically because I don't know the region of the sphere $f$ maps to. I of course can transform $(X,Y,Z)$ to spherical coordinates if it helps, but I guess this is not what you meant.

Comment: I see. I think I had the question backwards.